# How to enable a feature gate on the go?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to enable feature gate VolumeSubpathEnvExpansion on a 1.13 kubernetes cluster.
I did not found any information about enabling a feature gate for a running cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `--feature-gates=` to `kubelet`. Find systemd's or whatever init system you are using's and edit the kubelet start line to add in `VolumeSubpathEnvExpansion` and restart kublet service. It is a comma separated list so you might find that your kubelet already has `--feature-gates=` passed to it with other args.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/